# My factories are being autogenerated when I do `rake db:test:prepare`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, seed

When I run `rake db:test:prepare`,

It automagically generates my Factories :

```
require 'ffaker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|i| "marley_child#{i}@gmail.com" }
    password 'secret_shhh'
  end

  factory :brain do
    user FactoryGirl.create :user
  end

end
```

And then if I try to run `rspec` or even access my console with `rails c test`, I get a validation error :

```
/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

My Rspec :

```
  describe '#email' do
    context 'uniqueness' do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user, email: 'Foo@Bar.COM' }
      subject { user.errors }
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create :user, email: 'foo@bar.com'
        user.valid?
      end
      its(:messages) { should include(email: ['has already been taken']) }
    end
  end
```

What makes no sense to me is I assumed this data was transactional. Why are my factories getting generated when I prepare by data and not within each test? What is the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that this `factories.rb` was autogenerated when you did the `test:prepare`?

Comment: In any event, can you share the rest of the stack trace to see what's creating these database entries at startup?

Comment: There's no info. It shows it creating the DB, and then shows responses from my custom rake command. Says nothing about the factories.

Comment: Ah ok, this sort of makes sense. The factories are not created until I run the rspec. But then they're not deleted after the test is done ( which I thought is the definition of a transaction )

Comment: The creation of the factories (i.e. the `factories.rb` file), doesn't result in the creation of any objects, though. If you can share the stack trace, we can see what's creating the object (or invoking the factory, if that's the case).

Comment: My test is invoking the factory. Running `rspec`, ( pasted above ) creates the factories. The problem is is that I assumed that after running a test and pass/fail'ing it would then transactionally delete any created data during that test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35109/discussion-between-peter-alfvin-and-trip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one problem is that in your `:brain` factory definition, you're actually calling `FactoryGirl.create :user` as part of the definition of the factory when you presumably meant to call it when the factory is invoked (i.e. `user {FactoryGirl.create :user}`).

As for why there is already a `User` in the database, I can't answer that except to say that sometimes even if you're running with transactions turned on and things go south, records can be left behind.

Comment: Was there really no `User` in the database already? If so, that would suggest that that factory girl blocks are getting executed more than once during initialization and the sequence mechanism you had wasn't resulting in unique emails.